# how to get the coordinates of the center of a circle using d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to know how to obtain the central point of a circle to place my marker dynamically. In my real project, my circle can be in a random position within the svg, and I must locate my marker so that the bottom tip of this, is located in the center of the circle.

[image]

How can I do this?

```
  <body>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    const svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width",1000).attr("height",1000);

    svg.append("circle").attr("r",5).attr("cx",100).attr("cy",200).style("stroke","#FF0000");

    var widthMarker=50;
    var img = svg.append("svg:image")
        .attr("xlink:href", "marker.svg")
        .attr("width", widthMarker)
        .attr("height", widthMarker)
        .attr("x", 228)
        .attr("y",53)


  </script>
  </body>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/vFtJkZ1GKmyGYIUR0wXR?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, **name** your selections:

```
var circle = svg.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 5)
    .attr("cx", 100)
    .attr("cy", 200)
    .style("stroke", "#FF0000");
```

That being said, back to your question:

First, use `getBBox()` to get the circle's coordinates (provided that there is **no** translation), assuming that you don't know, for whatever reason, its location (that is, neither its `cx` nor its `cy` values):

```
var circleBox = circle.node().getBBox();
```

Then, use those coordinates to set the `x` and `y` positions:

```
.attr("x", circleBox.x + circleBox.width/2 - widthMarker/2)
.attr("y",circleBox.y + circleBox.height/2 - widthMarker)
```

Here is the updated Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/DYlJsUhrF1OgoChq927L?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Let `cx` represent the circle x position, `cy` the circle y position and `mw` the width of the marker, the formula is:

```
markerX = cx - mw / 2;
markerY = cy - mw;
```

Updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SETgRfK87GtjqvYjjKsT?p=preview):

```
var cx = 100,
  cy = 200;

svg.append("circle").attr("r", 5).attr("cx", cx).attr("cy", cy).style("stroke", "#FF0000");

var mw = 50;
var img = svg.append("svg:image")
  .attr("xlink:href", "marker.svg")
  .attr("width", mw)
  .attr("height", mw)
  .attr("x", cx - mw / 2)
  .attr("y", cy - mw);
```